# get records that last record binded with it have a specific value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this case[image]

where there is 2 tables:

**book** for example

```
id || --
1  || 
2  || 
3  ||
```

and  **loan** for example:

```
id | booId  | duration
1  | 1      | 4
2  | 1      | 6
3  | 1      | **5 (last one for book1)**
4  | 2      | 2
5  | 2      | 3
6  | 3      | 8
7  | 3      | **(5 not the last one so i don't need book3)**
8  | 3      | 6
9  | 2      |  **5 (last one for book2)**
```

I need to get all books id , where the last loan duration equals , so in this example it will be : [1,2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses aggregation:

```
select book_id
from loans l
group by book_id
having max(id) = max(case when duration = 5 then id end);
```

This checks that the last id for a given book matches the last id for a given book with the duration you want.